# How to make Outlook 2007 as default for emails while sending files directly from Word or Excel as attachments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

When I send any file from Microsoft Word or Excel 2007 directly by clicking on Send email, it  goes through Microsoft Outlook Express.

I want it to go through Microsoft Outlook 2007, which is my default email program.

Answer (score 1):

Is Microsoft Outlook 2007 set as your default Mail client?

Click start and type "default programs".
Then click "Set your Default programs".

Either choose or Set Outlook 2007 as your default program.

Comment: The question says that Outlook is set as the default email program.

Comment: @fixer1234. Yes but there is no harm in making sure by doing the above.

Comment: @RohitGupta: This is an ancient thread and a comment from over a year ago; it probably showed up in a review queue and I didn't notice the age.  I'm guessing that I saw the 1st sentence of the answer, which suggested that slotishtype had missed that point in the question.  You're right that there's no harm.  However, suggesting to double check just in case would be more appropriate as a comment, rather than an answer, since it would be a long shot to be the solution in this case given the last sentence of the question.  SU is a knowledgebase and answers are intended to be definitive solutions.

Comment: @fixer1234, Sorry, I did not look at the date.  And you are correct, it should not have been a reply.  I haven't a clue why it popped up in front of me as I was not searching for either outlook or Word.